# Is it already possible to visit Neom in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: saudi-arabia, neom, the-line

There is a lot of talk on the Internet about the new planned cities in the north of Saudi Arabia, such as 'The Line' or 'Neom'.

I wonder if any parts are already open and if it's possible yet to visit the site.

Could anyone share any practical experience?

Answer (score 5):

I've been following the project pretty closely, and while there's nothing physically stopping you from visiting the general area (it's about 2 hours by car from Tabuk), as of 2024 there's **absolutely nothing ready yet**: as you can see from the drone footage in this [February 2024 update](https://youtu.be/jJ8qpA8bByE?feature=shared), The Line is nothing but a rather large gash in the sand so far. The [very first hotel](https://www.factriyadh.com/saudi-arabia/neom/hotels-neom/hampton-by-hilton-sharma-is-the-first-hotel-to-open-in-neom/) did open in January, but it's a distinctly un-flashy [Hampton Inn](https://www.hilton.com/en/hotels/numsahx-hampton-sharma/) and appears to be limited to Neom personnel anyway.

The first Neom destination to actually open will be Sindalah Island, which is [scheduled to open later this year](https://www.arabianbusiness.com/industries/travel-hospitality/inside-sindalah-saudis-luxury-island-destination-first-neom-project-to-open).  None of the three hotels there have actually announced opening dates though, so I'm not holding my breath.  And any of the *really* crazy stuff (The Line, the Trojena ski resort, [the underwater city](https://www.neom.com/en-us/regions/aquellum) etc) won't open for another few years, if ever.